# What can I do with computer besides changing the processor when it doesn't support virtualization?

Tags: virtualization, hardware-virtualization

My computer doesn't support hardware virtualization. What can I do?

If I install any kind of software will it help or is there any solution available for this problem besides changing the processor?

Comment: "My computer doesn't support hardware virtualization what can I do" Upgrade the processor if you can or buy a PC that does support it.

Comment: @sadad Can you please provide the model of your CPU and motherboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt it is a processor limitation. It is a setting in the BIOS, or a BIOS limitation.

So you can find the setting in the BIOS, or upgrade your BIOS if it isn't there, or get a new motherboard(which will have a different BIOS). Changing the processor will have no impact.

Comment: Your answer is wrong, the CPU ***has*** to support virtualization (Either VT-x or AMD-v) If the CPU doesn't support it, changing the motherboard/BIOS will do nothing

Comment: Sure. But how many CPUs are around today that don't support it? That's why I wrote _'I doubt it is a processor limitation...'_

Comment: a surprising number actually. Intel uses VT as a line differentiation item, so it costs a couple bucks more. not somthing that means anything to the consumer, but large OEMs like HP or whatever often lack VT.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know for sure that it's your processor that doesn't support hardware virtualization rather than it simply being disabled in your BIOS?

Unfortunately, if your processor doesn't support it, there are no alternative solutions for you other than changing the processor or buying/using a computer with a different processor.